# Knockout: Template instantiation in same HTML element

Tags: knockout.js

Given a view model with the following structure:

```
- Root
    - Rows []
       - Record
       - Values[]
           - Source
           - Target
```

I'd like to put this in a table like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
     <tr><th>#</th><th>Source</th><th>Target</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Rows">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: Record"></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <!--- This row should repeat for every item in 'Values' --->
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-bind="text:Source"></td>
        <td data-bind="text:Target"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Is this possible with knockout? If not, what are my alternatives? I want to put the values of the 'Values' array in the same table, to ensure that the columns will properly resize with the columns in the table head.

Comment: Do you want to repeat the whole `tr` or only the three `td`s?

Comment: put a virtual binding foreach around the second tr with the values as the binding accessor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a knockout virtual element with foreach binding on it :

```
    <table>
    <thead>
         <tr><th>#</th><th>Source</th><th>Target</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Rows">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: Record"></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>

    <!-- ko foreach: Values -->
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td data-bind="text:Source"></td>
            <td data-bind="text:Target"></td>
        </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->  
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Ref: [Using text without a containing element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/text-binding.html)